# Azure PowerShell add User or Group to Service Principal

Tags: azure, powershell

how can i add users or a group to a service principal in azure with powershell?

My Service Principal:

```
$servicePrincipal = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "My Application"
```

i want to add the user test@domain.de or the group "IT" to this service principal.

EDIT: Or the AppRoleAssignmentRequired set to "false" would be fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution how to disable that role assignment is required.
I post the solution before i delete the thread. Maybe this helps someone.

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayname eq 'My Application'" | set-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppRoleAssignmentRequired $true
```